# MaterialUI intellisence not working in VS Code React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, material-ui

I am facing an issue. VS code does not suggest Intellisence for MaterialUI. I have to manually import the packages. I tried creating a new project and installing MUI but it did not work either. It worked yesterday and suddenly it stopped today.

I tried

- Creating a new app and install MUI
- Reinstalling MUI

Nothing worked. What can I do for this.